# Assign Box Register in Lua

Tags: luatex, context

I would like to implement the following in Lua, for various reasons. Recursion in a macro language is bad idea - the *definition* below exceeds the input stack size. I want to avoid TeX for a bisection font size search. Etc.

You can ignore this. The MWE is further down.

```
% Exceeds input stack size.
\newbox\fittedtextbox
% {1 width} {2 height} {3 starting font size} {4 font step} {5 minimum font size}
\def\startfittedtext#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \def\boxsize#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \setbox\fittedtextbox\vbox{%
            \definebodyfontenvironment[#3]
            \switchtobodyfont[#3]
            \hsize=#1
            \emergencystretch=1ex
            \tolerance=4000
            \hyphenpenalty=8000
            \getbuffer[fittedtext]}}
    \def\stopfittedtext{%
        \stopfittedtextargs{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
        \ruledvbox to #2{\unvbox\fittedtextbox}}
    \def\stopfittedtextargs#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \boxsize{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
        \ifdim\ht\fittedtextbox>#2
            \stopfittedtextargs{#1}{#2}{\dimexpr#3-#4\relax}{#4}{#5}
        \fi}
    \dostartbuffer[fittedtext][startfittedtext][stopfittedtext]}

\startfittedtext{7cm}{7cm}{12pt}{1pt}{1pt}
\input knuth
\stopfittedtext
```

The core operation is the assignment to a box register. This is what I need to replicate in Lua.

```
\setbox0=\vbox{...}
```

As far as I can tell ConTeXt doesn't provide the appropriate Lua API. The `context.*` function are output functions. The `vbox` will be outputted and `tex.box[0]` receives the return value of `context.vbox`, probably `nil` (haven't checked).

```
\startluacode
tex.box[0] = context.vbox(function() context.input("knuth") end)
\stopluacode
```

This is more subtle. The TeX stream is only executed when the Lua code block exits. So `tex.box[0]` references the value from *before* the Lua code block.

```
\def\coreop#1{\setbox0=\vbox{#1}}
\startluacode
context.coreop(function() context.input("knuth") end)
context("%spt", tex.box[0].height/65536)
\stopluacode
```

Same problem with this:

```
\startluacode
context("\\setbox0=\\vbox{\\input knuth }")
context("%spt", tex.box[0].height/65536)
\stopluacode
```

I did find this email[1] but wow, that's not what I want. It did mention that a higher-level API is on the horizon. Hopefully similar to `context.vbox` but returning a node (is this what a register is?) rather than outputting a box. If it has materialized, I'd appreciate an example. If not, there must be some workaround. A way to flush the TeX stream, or anything else.

[1] [lua equivalent of vbox...ht](https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2009-September/001044.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `tex.runtoks` which runs a local TeX loop:

```
\starttext
\def\coreop#1{\setbox0=\vbox{#1}}
\startluacode
tex.runtoks(function()
  context.coreop(function() context.input("knuth") end)
end)
context("%spt", tex.box[0].height/65536)
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

Comment: Interesting. Re. `tex.runtoks`: [You have to make sure that at the end TEX is in a sane state and this is not always trivial](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf#%232218). I wonder what this means in terms of a function that should accept any valid TeX.

Comment: @user19087 Well, as long as you "only" do \coreop where everything is wrapped in `\vbox{...}` anyway it should be safe.

Comment: Ironically I am keeping as much TeX out of Lua as possible. Otherwise I have to deal with nested `runtoks` for converting `ex` to `sp` at the proper font size. Also searching for how to convert `1ex` to `sp` isn't easy. Possibly put an "x" in a `vbox` and measure the height, but there are probably lots of gotchas for conforming to TeX's conversion. Could be another question if I used this approach.

Comment: `tex.runtoks(context.delayed.coreop(context.delayed.input("knuth")))`